# Custom environments in terraform on aws

Tags: terraform

I need to create a setup with terraform and aws where I could have the traditional Dev, Stage and Prod environments. I also need to allow creation of custom copies of individual services in those environments for developers to work on. I will use workspaces for Dev, Stage and Prod but can't figure out how to achieve these custom copies of services in environments.

An example would be a lambda in dev environment that would be called "test-lambda-dev". It would be deployed with the dev environment. The developer with initials "de" would need to work on some changes in this lambdas code and would need a custom version of it deployed alongside the regular one. So he would need to create a "test-lambda-dev-de".

I have tried to solve it by introducing a suffix after the resources name that would normally be empty but someone could provide a value signalling that a custom version is needed. Terraform destroyed the regular resource and replaced it with the custom one so it has not worked as intended.

Is there a way to get it to work? If not how can developers work on resources without temporarily breaking the environment?

Comment: This really isn't how Terraform works. If you want an *extra* copy of a Lambda function deployed, you have to declare it as another resource in Terraform. Expecting Terraform to deploy a new version of something because you changed the name, instead of updating/replacing the existing resource to have the new name, shows that you haven't taken the time to understand what Terraform does.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought it could be achieved somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to create a terraform module.  I would normally manage all of this using multiple repos, but here is an example of how to do it one, for simplicity:

```
/modules/my_module/main.tf (and as many .tf's as you want to define your service
/roots/production/main.tf (and more .tf's)
/roots/staging/main.tf (and more .tf's)
/roots/development/main.tf (and more.tf's)
```

Then, your production/main.tf would look like this:

```
module my_module {
  source = "../../modules/my_module
  environment_prefix = "prod"
}
```

In the staging/dev `main.tf`'s you will change this environment prefix accordingly.

In `my_module/main.tf` you could have:

```
variable environment_prefix {
  type = string
}

resource aws_instance my_instance {
  tags {
    Name = "${var.environment_prefix}-host"
  }

}
```

I glossed over some stuff there to make it easy to explain.  In the long run, you can publish your module to your source code repo and then developers can install it wherever/however they want by naming the repo in the `source` and then giving it their own prefix.